# How to use doxygraph?

Tags: javascript, perl, uml, doxygen, diagram

I'm trying to use [doxygraph](https://github.com/jitsuCM/doxygraph) to generate class diagrams, and to start with it and following README instructions I'm going with the examples.

Problem is that I see no result, I was expecting to see something on `doxygraph/doxyviz/index.html`.

What I did so far:

```
git clone https://github.com/jitsuCM/doxygraph.git
cd doxygraph/
perl doxygraph/doxygraph examples/doxygen/xml/d0/d01/class_file_name_iterator.xml doxyviz/htdocs/graph.dot
```

After that I check `doxygraph/doxyviz/index.html` using Safari but I see nothing beside `Select All`, `Select None` and `Show Diagram` buttons. If I click them nothing happens.

Any suggestios on how to proceed?

Comment: Why not use doxygen directly? Doxygen also produces graphs. looks to me that the doxygraph project is a bit dead (no changes for 7 years)

Comment: I was thinking perhaps doxygraph will give more/different diagrams than doxygen. Not sure if that's the case?